# How to use redux-undo module in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, redux

I'm using meteor. I'd like to use `redux-undo` to develope

I have installed like this

```
meteor npm install redux-undo
```

And use

```
import undoable, { ActionCreators } from 'redux-undo';
```

The meteor always shows this errors

> `Cannot find module 'redux-undo'`

However, I install the `redux` module and import as above, it works well. :(

Some one help me, thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried the same using ```meteor npm install --save redux-undo```

Comment: No, I think the --save option to only write module name to thi package.json